# Reformulating a Euclidean distance minimization problem into a semidefinite program

Tags: optimization, euclidean-geometry, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming, second-order-cone-programming

The following minimization problem is a Euclidean distance form of a single-facility location problem

$$\min \quad \sum_j \sqrt {(x-a_j)^2+(y-b_j)^2}$$

where $(x,y)$ and $(a_j,b_j)$ are the coordinates of the new facility and  current facilities, respectively.

I mistakenly tried to reformulate it as a second-order conic program (SOCP) and found that it is not possible. I wonder, is it possible to reformulate it as a convex program using semidefinite cones?

Comment: Your premise is wrong. This is indeed SOCP representable, as Johan says. But formulating SOCPs as QCPs is not straightforward, because not all SOCPs *can* be formulated as QCPs. Each solver has a specific way of representing SOCPs.

Comment: As you said, the issue here is going from SOCP to QCP. Thanks @Johan for his reformulation $s+t$ subject to $|q||≤t,||p||≤s$, I forgot to add non-negativity on $t,s$. Hence, the problem becomes QCP as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's SOCP representable, in fact it almost doesn't get more SOCP than this.

For instance, minimizing  $||q|| + ||p||$ is equivalent to minimizing $s + t$ subject to $||q||\leq t, ||p||\leq s$ which is an SOCP in standard form.

Comment: No it is not SOCP representable.
I tried epigraph form to reformulate it as SOCP, i.e. QCP.
I hesitated and I programmed it in CPLEX and GUROBI.
And I qot this error: Q matrix is not positive semi-definite (PSD)

Comment: Johan is correct that this is easy to formulate in SOCP form.

Comment: Perhaps you should use a modelling tool such as YALMIP or CVX to make sure it is done correctly.

Comment: I'm guessing that the problem here is the assumption that you can go from SOCP -> QCP.

Comment: I believe a typical mistake is to forget to add non-negativity on the convexity-destroying term, i.e. the SOCP $||q||\leq t$ is written as the quadratic constraint $q^Tq-t^2\leq 0$ when using cplex etc, and it is crucial to include $t\geq 0$, otherwise the model is not a QCP version of a SOCP.

Comment: Well, CPLEX still has to recognize that the Q matrix in an SOCP has that single negative eigenvalue... I don't recall having to explicitly declare $t \geq 0$ but you could be right. I've had CPLEX working with CVX in test but never got the full support I needed to finish the job.

Comment: I tested and removed the non-negativity bound and then cplex complained about Q not being positive semi-definite